# how to add semi transparent overlay on imageview in android studio and show it properlay

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

This is the image I am using and i want add a red transparent overlay
[Orignal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgfnI.jpg)

I want add an semitransparent overlay on this image
I used this code but i completly hiding the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <gradient
    android:startColor="#ffcccb"
    android:centerColor="#ffcccb"
    android:endColor="#ffcccb"
    />
 </shape>

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backgroudImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="254dp"
            android:rotation="0"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:foreground="@drawable/image_overlay"
            android:src="@drawable/backgroud"
            />
```

how to adjust color codes How to decrease Opacity
I want to show my Image view as shown in this image[This is the view i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEyX9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for black:

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Now if I want to use opacity then you can use the below code:

```
<color name="black">#99000000</color> <!-- 99 is for alpha and others pairs zero's are for R G B -->
```

And below for opacity code: and all [opacity level here](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4)

**Hex Opacity Values**

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

also you can change alpha value on attributes layout.
you can write to image alpha 0.5

Comment: I'm very happy to hear that if you think it's useful then you should pick this answer :)